# Complex Password Breaking KeyTool command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, passwords, keytool

I know this is something stupid, but hoping someone can point me in the right direction...  I have a script to add a pfx file to a keystore.  It searches a specific folder for a *.pfx file, then prompts for the password for the *.pfx file, then imports it into the keystore.  The problem portion of my script is:

```
$pfxPwd = Read-Host "Enter password for PFX file"
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $pfxName -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass $pfxPwd -destkeystore $keystore -srcalias $pfxAlias -destalias $serverFullNameValue -storepass $mypwd
```

This works fine most of the time, but if the password contains a specific character (I've narrowed it down to >, ', +, <, [, #, . or (, but not sure which - though you can probably see it immediately), it seems to break the command and lists out all the different switches that I can use with KeyTool.  Is there something specific I should be doing with my $pfxPwd variable to ensure that it will accept the password, regardless of the characters that are in it?

Comment: In Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) up to v7.2.x only, when calling external programs the only problematic character is `"`, which you'd have to escape as `\"` (v7.3+ does that for you automatically). Additional effort would only be needed if `keytool` were a _batch file_. Is it? (What does `Get-Command keytool` indicate?)

Comment: CommandType - Application
Name - Keytool.exe
Version - 8.0.2420.8
Source C:\folder

Comment: Then I have no explanation. Here's a sample command that uses `choice.exe` to echo an argument containing the characters you mention, and you'll see that it is passed correctly (ignore the `[Y,N]Y` suffix): `$pfxPwd = ">',+,<,[,#("; choice /d Y /t 0 /m $pfxPwd`